# hex string to datetime format

Tags: java, datetime, hex

I am converting hex-string into a dateformat... I am getting wrong date time with the following.. not sure where I am making a mistake.

```
    String s1="07:db:0c:08:16:0d:1e:00";    //2011-12-8,22:13:30.0
    s1 = s1.replaceAll(":", "");
    String year = s1.substring(0, 4);
    String month = s1.substring(4, 6);
    String day = s1.substring(6, 8);
    String hour = s1.substring(8, 10);
    String minute = s1.substring(10, 12);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(year, 16));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(month, 16));
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(day, 16));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(hour, 16));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minute, 16));
   System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

my output is 'Mon Jan 09 10:13:49 CST 2012'.. which is not correct (it should be 2011-12-8,22:13:30.0 -- format ignored for now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Month in Java is represented by integer literals 0..11, that is January is 0, ..., and December is 11. In this code, `Integer.parseInt(month, 16)` returns 12, which the Calendar object shifts to January next year (by increasing year).

-EDIT-
Also, set `HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `HOUR` in `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(hour, 16));`

Answer (score 2):

Few notes:

1. Month in the Calendar class is [from 0-11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH), where 0 is January.
2. [The toString format may vary](http://Return%20a%20string%20representation%20of%20this%20calendar.%20This%20method%20is%20intended%20to%20be%20used%20only%20for%20debugging%20purposes,%20and%20the%20format%20of%20the%20returned%20string%20may%20vary%20between%20implementations.%20The%20returned%20string%20may%20be%20empty%20but%20may%20not%20be%20null.).
3. You forgot the seconds:

   ```
   String second = s1.substring(12, 14);
   cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(second, 16));
   ```